# A good and free local proxy switching program for windows?

Tags: windows, proxy

A program that would let me easily switch between proxies in windows, and even if possible let me split the load between them.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Read the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/129577/a-good-program-to-add-proxy-functionability-to-all-windows-programs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not what you're looking for in this particular case, but I use a [Google Chrome extension called Proxy Switchy!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj) Off course this requires you to have a browser open, but in my case it is 100% of the time.

[image]

---

Since Chrome uses the system proxy settings (on Windows, IE proxy settings) because it doesn't have its own proxy settings yet (see crbug.com/266).
Therefore, changing Chrome's proxy settings using Switchy will also affect the system proxy settings.

---

### Features

```
- Manage and switch between multiple proxy profiles.
- Change the proxy configuration of Chrome and IE in one click.
- URL based switch rules.
- Supports Socks v4 and v5.
- Change LAN and VPN/Dial-up proxy settings.
- Quickly add rules for currently active websites.
- Quick proxy switch between two profiles or cycle all profiles.
- Online rule list support (AutoProxy compatible).
- Export switch rules as PAC/RuleList file.
- Backup/Restore options.
- Proxy change monitoring.
- Colorful profiles and icons.
- Supports Windows and Linux (32/64 bit) -- OS X support is planned.
- and more are coming!
```

Comment: Thank you i had this installed yet this method of use had not occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this [Proxy swither tool](http://soft-net.net/IEProxySwitch.aspx) its support IE, Chrome, Safari and maxthon browsers