# A good program to add proxy functionability to all windows programs?

Tags: windows-7, proxy

I installed [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) an application that makes applications (that might not use the IE proxy settings) use a specific proxy, but right after installing it Windows Live Messenger stopped working. I was looking for alternative programs?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can set Windows Live Messenger's proxy through the 'Connections' tab in the 'Options' menu.

Comment: Mohammad, please add your solution as an answer below, then mark it as accepted.

Comment: I didn't know we could do that : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/) Service edition which was the most stable out of the ones I found. Worked perfectly.